# App crashes if Games.API is added

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-client

Basically, The googleApiClient is able to connect. But If I add Games.API to the APIclient, then some uncaught exception occurs. I searched almost everywhere, but no one seems to have this problem. As soon as I remove Games.API from the Builder, it gets connected normally.
But I need Games.API to include Leaderboards in my game.
Please can somebody help me?

Logcat:

```
07-09 00:43:19.709  14636-14636/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418c49a8)
07-09 00:43:19.709  14636-14636/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
07-09 00:43:19.709  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzc.zznQ(Unknown Source)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 00:43:19.724  14636-14636/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
07-09 00:43:19.725  14636-14636/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzc(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzc.zznQ(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzi$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest:

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="480680880602" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="480680880602" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Code:

```
  mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
  .addApi(Drive.API)
  .addApi(Games.API)
  .addApi(AppStateManager.API)
  .addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE)
  .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
  .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
  .build();

 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

        Toast.makeText(Homepage.this, "CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SharedPreferences load=getSharedPreferences("mysavegame", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int a=load.getInt("score", 0);

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      //      Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, "CgkI2tPA1v4NEAIQAA", a);
        }
        Toast.makeText(Homepage.this, "SCORE SUBMITTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Connected to Google Play services!
        // The good stuff goes here.
    }
```

Game link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iitb.nihar.declarecardgame

Comment: You might consider using a separate GoogleApiClient just for the Games API. The Google Play Games lifecycle (users logging in & out from Google Play Games) can (or should, according to Google: https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) be kept somewhat independent of the rest of your game's interaction, and consequently would be kept separate from the lifecycle of other Google APIs. Can't say if it will actually help with your exception, but it may be worth trying and may be a good design change in any case.

Comment: Tried that, but still in vain. Same problem still exists.

Comment: Out of ideas. Is there anything else in the log at the time of the error that could be relevant? What you posted looks filtered down to just your app process.

Comment: Don't know if you've been able to make progress, but I came across this, which may help you troubleshoot the issue: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/logging

Comment: Part of your problem is that you cannot hard code the app_id into the manifest. I found this discussion because I was getting the exact same error as you. I had an invalid app_id and it caused the crash. No app_id defined properly will also cause this crash. Need to define it in the res/values.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a complete solution to your problem, but definitely part of the issue is that you are hard coding the app_id into your manifest. That wont work. Just tried it and I get the same crash.

You need to use the "@string/app_id" to reference a res/values/something.xml file.

**This will work if you add the value for app_id like shown below to the /res/values/strings.xml file.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

This will **not** work.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="123456789" />
```

**In /res/values/strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_id">123456789</string>
</resources>
```

Even if you put an app_id in /res/values/file.xml, if it is not a valid app_id, you will also get the the same crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. I use Eclipse as IDE, and Eclipse will access AndroidManifest for checking `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion`. And I dont know the reason exactly but `Games.API` will work if `targetSdkVersion` is > 19. So:

1. Make a copy of Google Play Service from `ANDROID_HOME/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib` to the same folder of your project (actually same hard disk partition).
2. Change AndroidManifest.xml file of Google Play Service and your project also to `<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>`

If the exception keep showing or you are using Android Studio. You can try upgrade you google play service sdk and goole play service on your device to the newest(https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/489)